# r combining data based on differece

Tags: r, leaflet

Is there a way to merge two data frames based on their difference? For example say we have this data frame...

```
set.seed(1234)
example1 = data.frame(Area=c("Zone1","Zone2","Zone3","Zone4"),
                       X1a=sample(10,4), X1b=sample(10,4), X1c=sample(10,4),
                       X1d=sample(10,4), X1e=sample(10,4))

example1
#   Area X1a X1b X1c X1d X1e
#1 Zone1   9   3   1  10   3
#2 Zone2   3  10   2   8  10
#3 Zone3  10   9   7   1   5
#4 Zone4   2   2   4   4   2
```

And we do some operations like this and we end up with...

```
example2<-example1[-c(2,4),]
example2
#   Area X1a X1b X1c X1d X1e
#1 Zone1   9   3   1  10   3
#3 Zone3  10   9   7   1   5
```

Is there a way to combine these two based on the difference between them, for example say I want to combine example2 with example1, is there a way to end up like this?

```
example3<-combineDiff(original=example2, use= example1)

example3
#   Area X1a X1b X1c X1d X1e
#1 Zone1   9   3   1  10   3
#2 Zone2   3  10   2   8  10
#3 Zone3  10   9   7   1   5
#4 Zone4   2   2   4   4   2
```

So we dont end up with duplicates of Zone1 and Zone3 rows? Also is there a way to change the values of these new rows? For example something like this?

```
example3<-combineDiff(original=example2, use=example1, newRows=0)

example3
#   Area X1a X1b X1c X1d X1e
#1 Zone1   9   3   1  10   3
#2 Zone2   0   0   0   0   0
#3 Zone3  10   9   7   1   5
#4 Zone4   0   0   0   0   0
```

I´m asking because I´m working with visualizing some data with leaflet and r, And I´m running into trouble when I sample the data(for example "show only data from men" or "people over 50"). The way I have set it up is that the data gets subsetet based on checkboxinput and it´s frequent that I end up with fewer rows then the zones I´m trying to visualize, which messes up the output, so I would need a way to reinsert the the lost rows/zones and change their value so I know that they should be zero or NA.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing in the third step, `example3` looks identical to `example1`

Comment: Is there only one row per zone in either df?

Comment: Start with `part<-use[!use$Area %in% original$Area,]` to get the part of the second argument which is not present in the original. Then you can `rbind` it to `original`, optionally changing its values to `newRows` (for instance `part[-1]<-newRows`).

Comment: **mtoto**: yeah it ends up being the same, thats intended.
**user3949008**: In my actual dataframe yeah, one row per zone.
@nicola Gonna give this a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case first (or both) data frames have one row per Area value, you can try:

```
example <- rbind(example1[!example1$Area %in% example2$Area, ], example2)
```

If you want to arrange them back by Area column, you can do:

```
example <- example[sort(example$Area), ]
```